# Making dynamic object array issue?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, class, dynamic

```
Candidate::Candidate ()
{

}
```

Its not doing any thing.
Not writing it as it is can't execute the line:

```
Candidate *list = new Candidate [10];
```

Why?

```
Error: no default constructor exists for the class "Candidate"
```

Comment: And you're sure your candidate class actually has a constructor that has no parameters or all default parameters? Anyway, I'd suggest `std::vector`.

Comment: The compiler have answered your question very well :)

Comment: Look in your class definition, are you sure you define a constructor? I'm with @chris I'd use vectors also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow your dynamic array allocation, `new Candidate[10]`, a default constructor of `Candidate` must be available. That is, it must be able to take no arguments. If you provide any of your own constructors for `Candidate`, regardless of how many arguments they take, the implicit default constructor that is usually defined automatically by the compiler will not be defined. You therefore have to provide it yourself, even if its body is empty. See §12.1/5:

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

Your class would be fine as follows because the compiler will implicitly define a defaulted default constructor:

```
class Candidate
{ }; // Compiler provides a default constructor
```

But as soon as you give it any other constructor, the implicit default constructor is not provided any more:

```
class Candidate
{
 public:
  Candidate(int x);
  // A user-defined constructor is provided so the default constructor
  // must be defined explicitly
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an additional constructor in your class. If you have any constructor defined, the compiler won't generate a default one.

Comment: You mean to say when ever I define a constructor that is not a default, I must give definition of default with it too?

Comment: Basically, yes - if you want to allow creating instances of your class without passing parameters (it won't be called "default" in this case because you define it manually, just a constructor with no parameters)

Comment: It's still called the default constructor, because it is called by default when no argument list is provided.  The differentiating term is "compiler-generated".

Comment: @icepack It's still a default constructor, just not a defaulted default constructor (unless you `= default` it).